# Why does my delete button not work unless I use a different delete button in a different div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JavaScript and trying to create a todo app and when I hover my active lists, I want to be able to delete the content of that list while it's active. Instead, it deletes the content when I click on a div with dummy data on it that I use just for reference that also has a delete button. These are the snippets that I need help with.

I am not sure what else to write down. Apparently I need more words just to ask this specific question so I am just randomly writing just so I can push this out and ask for help.

https://jsfiddle.net/delo2795/xbp8vfeh/5/

```
const listsContainer = document.querySelector('[data-lists]')

listsContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
        selectedListId = e.target.dataset.listID
        
        console.log(selectedListId)
        saveAndRender()

        
    }

})

deleteListButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // find lists of tasks that is not selected
    lists = lists.filter(list => list.id !== selectedListId)
    // take the list that is selected and remove from memory
    selectedListId = null 

    saveAndRender()
})

newListForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Get information from the user form
    const taskInput = taskname.value 
    const assignInput = assign.value 
    const descriptionInput = description.value
    const dueDateInput = duedate.value 


    // user has to input something in the field
    // if (taskInput == null || taskInput === '') return
    // if (assignInput == null || assignInput === '') return
    // if (descriptionInput== null || descriptionInput === '') return
    // if (dueDateInput == null || dueDateInput === '') return
   
    // create List
    const list = createList(taskInput, assignInput, descriptionInput,dueDateInput)
    
    // Update the List
    lists.push(list)
    // save List to Browser and Show List on Browser
    saveAndRender()
})

function createList(taskInput, taskAssign, taskDescription, taskDueDate) {
    // Initializes the variables and saves it to list
    return { 
        id: Date.now().toString(), 
        taskInput: taskInput,
        taskAssign: taskAssign,
        taskDescription: taskDescription,
        taskDueDate: taskDueDate,
        taskCompleted: false
    } 
}

function render() {
    clearElement(listsContainer)
    lists.forEach(list => {

        // create new list item container
        const listElement = document.createElement('li')
        listElement.dataset.listID = list.id
        listElement.classList.add('list-group-item', 'shadow-lg', 'rounded')

        if (list.id === selectedListId) {
            listElement.classList.add('activeList')
        }
     }
}

render()
```

Comment: See [ask] for tips on what else to write and what to provide to make a good question. For instance, Providing HTML (and CSS) so that the code becomes a [mre] would not be remiss...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't want it to be super long so I included a jsfiddle

Comment: Please read [ask]. As it notes there, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS." Also, reread my comment; it asks for a ***minimal*** reproducible example, not your whole application. Narrow it down to just the code you need to ask about.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you. I will take a note of that the next time I ask. What do you think I am doing wrong in my app?

Comment: Hey, I made some changes on your jsfiddle file with the delete button working on each card you create. https://jsfiddle.net/etfzdca2/15/ (added Updated here as comment to see where I modified) . As an advices you need to assign the function to the delete button when you create it then you add the id of the card to the button like "dataID" attribute and on filter you delete the selected id from the click event. You will need to fix the Complete one that doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array to store the data. When a user clicks on a delete button (which will be assigned a function like DELETE(id)), the JS will delete it from the array and then rerender the notes from the array. This will help keep your app more structured.

Comment: got it, I will re-write my list into an array. In my case though, why isn't it deleting when it is hovered and I am clicking the delete button?

Comment: and that removes the id from memory so it gets deleted. if you look at the JSfiddle, the selectedListId = null only works when i click on the delete button that is in the Done column. But why isn't it getting deleted when I click the delete button while its being hovered?

Comment: @user2816227 yes, sorry about that, I misread your code.

Comment: I understood everything in your code except this: ` clearElement(listsContainer)`. Where is this function?

Comment: ChessAndCode it clears any dummy element that I might have

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I am as much puzzled as you as to why this is not working.

Comment: your welcome. hope you find the bug in this program. :)

Comment: by the way, after researching array vs lists, I disagree that this should have been an array. Arrays are specially optimised for arithmetic computations so if you’re going to perform similar operations you should consider using an array instead of a list. Also lists are containers for elements having differing data types but arrays are used as containers for elements of the same data type.